# Is it possible to use laravel traits to retrieve data from the models that they're called from

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits

Basically im doing a "enterprise application" and i want to make code as flexible as possible while keeping it somewhat scalable(its for personal use for now so i don't need to be ultra professional)

The thing is many entities share the same fields and since im trying to learn laravel more in depth i thought that the models (and by extention the traits) acted like some ORM's i've worked before where they would create the sql stuff for me.... they don't so i started doing the migrations but now i see that if i could acess certain columns in the traits it would make the code a lot cleaner and more understandable

basically what i want to do is something like

```php
trait hasValue{
   public function getStuff(){
      $ret = ModelAttachedTo::select("value", "price")->get();
      return $ret;
    }
}
```

Edit: I ended up realizing that with this and other shortcomings of laravel to just completely change back end although if a answer comes i will try to see if it fits the question and works as intended

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's simplier way to do this in laravel but in PHP world, you can do this with abstract methods. Traits can declare abstract methods which have to implemented by classes.

So declare an abstract "getPrice" method in trait. All of your classes have to implement that method. And you can call it whenever you want.

Comment: i guess i could use a abstract method but the code is always going to be exactly the same as i always use the same name for the column and want the exact same behaviour 
the only reason the columns aren't on the same table is due to denormalization of the database since its gonna have a lot of data some of which i will rarely fetch

Comment: I think i couldn't understand.. You can always send empty data when you didn't fetch data.. Or, you can write/use proxy pattern to fetch data when needed